# Ruby where with find_each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am looking at the official Rails documentation which shows how to use the "find_each" method. Here is an example they gave

```
Person.where("age > 21").find_each do |person|
  person.party_all_night!
end
```

This processes 1000 records at a time. However, I am still confused. How does this translate to SQL? What happens behind the scenes that allows Ruby to only process 1000 records at a time?

The reason I am sort of confused is because it seems Person.where("age > 21") would execute first, which would return ALL results.

For instance:

```
Person.where("age > 21").limit(10)
```

would return all persons in memory first, then give you the first 10, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Person.where("age > 21")` returns an ActiveRecord relation only. It doesn't return all the results.

`Person.where("age > 21").limit(10)` does NOT load all the models in memory, that would be awful and unusable. It just loads 10.

`find_each` doesn't really process 1000 records at a times. It loads 1000 records, and then process each one of them.

Comment: Person.where("age > 21") may look like it is returning all the results if you are evaluating it from the console.  Person.where("age > 21").class is informative.

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest running this from the console and looking at the SQL or reading the source code.

For example:

```
User.find_each(:batch_size => 40) do |user| end
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" >= 0) ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 40
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" > 96) ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 40
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" > 156) ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 40
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" > 219) ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 40
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" > 272) ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 40
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" > 314) ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 40
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" > 355) ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 40
```

Or

```
bundle show activerecord
point your favorite code editor at that location and find the source
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a cute lovely feature of Ruby, called *codeblocks*. What makes it really great, that *every* method is assuming to 〈silently〉 receive a codeblock as the last parameter. There is a possibility to dynamically check if the codeblock was given with `if block_given?`.

I guess you wonder why Ruby *returns* data with `where` alone and just *prepares* it with `where.whatever` chain? Well, `ActiveRecord`  implicitly checks, whether the codeblock was given and either executes the underlying SQL statement and iterates through result **or** returns an iterator with prepared but not yet executed SQL statement. The latter will be lazy executed and cached on demand. The same practice is used in, say, `Array.each`. Behind the scene something like that is being performed:

```
sql_prepare
if block_given?
  @cache = sql_execute_and_cache
  @cache.each { yield @cache }
end
```

Hope it helps.